# My c++ program concatenates strings where i dont tell him to

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

Hi I'm writing this small program for a homework i have on c++. 
It's about polynomials and it asks for the degree of the polynomial, the exponent, the coefficient and the constant to multiply the coefficient.
Now I have this code I've been making:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{    
    int deg=0, x=0, con, co;
    string m, n, poli="";
    ostringstream convert, convert1;

    cout<<"Hi! this program will show the resulting polynomial of multiplying the \npolynomial times the constant.\n\n";
    cout<<" ";
    cout<<"\n\nBut first give me the degree of the polynomial (max 9): "; cin>>deg;
    cout<<"\n\nNow the Multiplier constant: "; cin>>con;

    cout<<"\n\nNow give me the coefficients of the polynomial.\n";

    while(deg!=0){

        int n1=0, n2=0, n3=0;
        string m="", n="";
        convert.clear();
        convert1.clear();

        cout<<"Exponent " << deg <<" coefficient: "; cin >>co; cout<<"\n\n";

        if(co!=0){

            n2=(co*con);
            n3=(deg+0);

            convert << n2;
            convert1 << n3;
            m = convert.str();
            n = convert1.str();
            poli+=m+"x^"+n+" ";
            cout<<poli+"\n\n";        
        }

        deg--;
    }

}
```

but for some reason instead of outputting lets say 
`3x^4 2x^3 2x2`

... it out puts

3x^4 32x^43 322x^432

as you see it's concatenating for some reason and i don't know why, can you guys help me?

Comment: C++ is not C; not only is it unnecessary to declare all variables at the top of a block, it's actually poor form. You should declare your variable at the first point of usage and no sooner.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to misunderstand what the [std::basic_ios::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) function does. It does *not* clear the stream buffers. That means that every time you do

```
convert << n2;
convert1 << n3;
```

you *are* appending to the stream.

To fix this, make the stream variable `convert` and `convert1` local inside the loop, just like `m` and `n`.

Answer (score 0):

I've declared 'ostringstream convert,convert1;' inside the while loop and it works fine here. Your stream wasn't clearing out after each while loop iteration.